# Why does Swift lint ignore my custom regular expression?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftlint

My **.swiftlint.yml** file:

```
disabled_rules:
  - trailing_whitespace
  - mark
  - line_length
  - force_cast
  - variable_name
  - force_try
  - cyclomatic_complexity
  - function_body_length
  - type_body_length
  - file_length
  - type_name

excluded:
  - Pods

custom_rules:
  press_enter_after_object_definition:
    regex: "(class|enum).*"
```

The result is following:

[image]

Why it has found only first match?

I need to find every line with `enum` or `class` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.*`, this means match anything except a line break. So it appears to die in SwiftLint after the first line break of a successful match.

This works:

```
press_enter_after_object_definition:
    regex: "(class|enum)"
```